# JSON is cut short from HTTP response (Axios)

Tags: node.js, http, axios

I am using Axios in a Node.js (MERN stack) project to request data from the server. The result of the request is a large JSON string, but gets cut off prematurely. Strangely enough it sometimes works once if I start the backend and frontend servers fresh. The console output looks like this (someone please inline it, I dont have the reputation yet...):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcZ6B.png

On the backend:

```
app.route("/exercise/run").post(checkAuth ,function (req, res) {
    // doing some stuff (start child_process to run java program which returns json object)
    res.status(200).json(jsonObj);
}
```

On the frontend:

```
let options = {
    timeout: 10000,
    maxContentLength: 1000000000,
};
Axios.post('http://localhost:4000/exercise/run', data, options)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            let output = Buffer.from(response.data).toString();
            let json = JSON.parse(output); // this fails because it is cut short
            console.log(json);
        }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

I kind of expect to have it work every time, but thats is not the case. I wonder if I dont close the connection correctly or prematurely, but I have been searching for hours now and have not found a working fix.

I also tried to send it in chunks (even thought its not ment for that since I already know the size of the json and dont have to stream it), but that didnt work either. Same exact error, sometimes it works (usually when I restart everything), most of the time it gets cut off.

On the backend:

```
function splitAndSendJSON(res, json) {
    const CHUNCK_SIZE = 2000;

    let jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);

    let dataArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonString.length; i += CHUNCK_SIZE) {
        dataArray.push(jsonString.slice(i, i + CHUNCK_SIZE));
        console.log(i);
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf8',
        'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
    });
    // res.write("[");
    for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length-1; i++) {
        res.write(dataArray[i]);
    }
    res.write(dataArray[dataArray.length-1]);
    // res.write("]");
    res.end();
}
```

On the frontend:

```
let options = {
    timeout: 10000,
    responseType: 'stream',
    maxContentLength: 1000000000,
    headers: {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
        'keepAlive':true,
        'maxSockets':1
    }
};
Axios.post('http://localhost:4000/exercise/run', data, options)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            if (typeof response.data === "string") {
                let json= JSON.parse(response.data);
                console.log(json)
            } else if (typeof response.data === "object") {
                let output = Buffer.from(response.data).toString()
                console.log(output);
                let json= JSON.parse(output);
                console.log(json)
            } 
        }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: maybe increase timeout? `timeout: 1000 * 60`

Comment: I just tested it. Does not change the outcome. The response is pretty much instant anyways. Less than a second. I dont think thats it.

Comment: I removed the chunking and just send the json object directly, since I didnt need to stream it anyways. Yet, the exact same problem occurs. I updated the source code which is now a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it wasnt a HTTP issue at all. I was using child_process to spawn another process and that one seems to chunk the output. Since the HTTP response can only send data once, it only send the first chunk and stopped. I now push the process data into an array and send that one to the client.

```
res.dataArray = [];
child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log("stdout");
    if (data) {
        res.dataArray.push(data);
    }
});
child.on('close', function (exitCode) {
    console.log("close");
    console.log(exitCode);
    res.status(200).json(res.dataArray);
});
```

I have to concat the Buffer objects in the list to one Buffer object and parse that to JSON.

```
let buffers = [];
for (let buffer of response.data) {
    buffers.push(Buffer.from(buffer));
}

let finalBuffer = Buffer.concat(buffers);

let json = JSON.parse(finalBuffer.toString());
```

I might do this on the server side already, so that the client doesnt have to do that work and already receives the final json object instead.